# Do SQL Server Views update their data types automatically based on what tables feed them?

Tags: sql-server, view, datatypes

Someone mistakenly created a bunch of nchar fields in database tables.
I noticed this, and after examining the issue, we're moving these fields to nvarchar types and trimming the values inside.

In my script, I currently have it limited to pull only the tables that have nchar types, assuming that the views that are fed by the tables will know to update their values. **Is this assumption correct, or should I be including views in this list as well?**

For reference, the script in its current form is below (mostly taken from [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740935/convert-all-nchar-columns-to-nvarchar-columns-in-a-database-or-table)):

```
declare @tn nvarchar(128)
declare @cn nvarchar(128)
declare @ln int

declare @sql as nvarchar(1000)

declare c cursor for 
    select cols.table_name,cols.column_name,cols.character_maximum_length 
    from information_schema.columns cols
        inner join information_schema.tables tabs 
            on (cols.TABLE_SCHEMA = tabs.TABLE_SCHEMA and cols.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME)
    where cols.data_type ='nchar' and tabs.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 

open c
fetch next from c into @tn, @cn, @ln

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    set @sql = 'alter table ' + @tn + ' alter column ' 
        + @cn + ' nvarchar(' + convert(nvarchar(50), @ln) + ')'
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    set @sql = 'update ' + @tn + ' set ' + @cn + ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + @cn + '))'
    exec sp_executesql @sql

    fetch next from c into @tn, @cn, @ln
end

close c
deallocate c
```

**References**

- [Convert all NCHAR columns to NVARCHAR columns in a database or table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740935/convert-all-nchar-columns-to-nvarchar-columns-in-a-database-or-table)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(a INT, b NCHAR(4));
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vx AS 
  SELECT a, b FROM dbo.x;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.x ALTER COLUMN a TINYINT;
ALTER TABLE dbo.x ALTER COLUMN b NVARCHAR(4);
GO

SELECT a,b INTO #blat FROM dbo.vx;
GO

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#blat';
GO

DROP VIEW dbo.vx;
DROP TABLE dbo.x, #blat;
```

Partial output:

```
COLUMN_NAME    TYPE_NAME    PRECISION
-----------    ---------    ---------
a              tinyint      3
b              nvarchar     4
```

So, in practical terms, yes, any interaction with the view should yield the new data types.

**That said**, I would *always* call `sp_refreshview` for any views that reference a table that has changed (and in fact I often use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` so that I can't alter a table without knowing about the views and other objects it affects - this can make cowboy development/deployment painful, but I guess that's kind of the point).

You can build the script to refresh all referenced views dynamically like this (this is for a single table; you'll need to incorporate this into your existing script to make it dynamic for all affected tables):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sp_refreshview ''' 
  + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(v.name) + ''';'
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
INNER JOIN sys.views AS v
ON d.referencing_id = v.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE d.referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.whatever')
GROUP BY s.name, v.name;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Another reason you should always refresh all views after changing the base table(s), *especially* if your views use `SELECT *`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(a INT, b NCHAR(4));
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vx AS 
  SELECT * FROM dbo.x;
GO

SELECT * INTO #b1 FROM dbo.vx;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.x ALTER COLUMN a TINYINT;
ALTER TABLE dbo.x ALTER COLUMN b NVARCHAR(4);
GO

SELECT * INTO #b2 FROM dbo.vx;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.x ADD d INT;
GO

SELECT * INTO #b3 FROM dbo.vx;
GO

EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.x.b', N'c', N'COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.x.d', N'b', N'COLUMN';
GO

SELECT * INTO #b4 FROM dbo.vx;
GO

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#b1';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#b2';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#b3';
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#b4';
GO

DROP TABLE #b1, #b2, #b3, #b4;
GO
```

Partial results:

```
-- initial:

#b1____    a    int        10
#b1____    b    nchar      4

-- correct:

#b2____    a    tinyint    3
#b2____    b    nvarchar   4

-- missing new column d:

#b3____    a    tinyint    3
#b3____    b    nvarchar   4

-- missing column c, b still points at "old" b:

#b4____    a    tinyint    3
#b4____    b    nvarchar   4
```

But then if we refresh the view:

```
EXEC sp_refreshview N'dbo.vx';
GO

SELECT * INTO #b5 FROM dbo.vx;

EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_columns N'#b5';

DROP VIEW dbo.vx;
DROP TABLE dbo.x, #b5;
```

Results:

```
#b5____    a     tinyint     3
#b5____    c     nvarchar    4
#b5____    b     int         10
```

Note that the data types are correct now, but the columns are not in the order you would expect.

Comment: Great answer in several ways: made it understandable, gave an executable example, and provided two other tips I hadn't heard of before. Thank you! I'll be putting all of those (including testing with test tables, etc.) to use in the future.