# ODBC Connection Not Refreshing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, ms-query

I am trying to connect FedEx Shipping Manager Integration Assistant to a SQL 2008 R2 database.  I have a view created that has all the necessary fields to populate in the Integration Assistant.  The problem, I am having, is I can make a change to the view on the SQL box, and it's not getting to the Integration Assistant.

I have attempted a new Integration, but, the new fields are not showing up.  I have even attempted to use Excel and connect through using Microsoft Query, and I'm getting old data.  I can change the view, but, it won't show up in Microsoft Query.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the view? `exec sp_refreshview N'[dbo].[vMyView]'`

Comment: Funny, I was [just talking about this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61916/1186). In addition to running `sp_refreshview`, make sure your view doesn't use `SELECT *` - if you add the columns there explicitly, this type of thing shouldn't happen in the first place.

Comment: Shawn -- performed an sp_refreshview command completed.  No change in the integration

Comment: Aaron -- Would never use SELECT * for a view.  Everything is explicit.